# BeautifulSoup Repetitive link following

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a website using BeautifulSoup library in Python. In that I have to repetitively follow a starting link.

Inputs:**starting link**, **position** and **counts**

Consider a web page with n anchor tags(< a href=" "> ). Using the starting link I have to find go to the link at given **position** value.

From there I have to repeat above step **count** times. I have to return the last  element

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
#start_link=input("\nEnter the starting point\n")
start_link='http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Janae.html'

def get_last_link(link,position):
    temp_variable=urllib.urlopen(link).read()
    soup_variable=BeautifulSoup(temp_variable)
    tags_variable=soup_variable('a')
    t=tags_variable[position].get('href',None)
    return t

def loop(link,times,i):
    #link=start_link
    while i<times:
        temp=get_last_link(link,7)
        i+=1
        print temp
        loop(temp,times,i)

loop(start_link,18,0)
```

Help me with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a break after the last loop.

Comment: And remove the last loop(temp, times, i) in the loop function if you want to stop the count at 18.

Comment: Ignore my last comment and just put a break after the loop.